# I'm not able to search for specific files in a folder saved on SD card on Macbook air

Tags: sd-card

I have a folder saved on my SD card with many different files. When i go to search in my SD card, and search for a specific file in that folder the page shows completely blank & that file does not show up! Even-though the file i'm searching for is in that folder and can be found manually.
Is there any solution for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You should try the cool, (and free,) app [EasyFind](https://www.devontechnologies.com/apps/freeware) by developer Devon Technologies. It searches for files where Finder can't search well, or can't search at all. I use it at work for searching for files in very complex macOS folder structures shared on Windows servers, and it is fast.

Alternate [download site](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/11076/easyfind).

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm a very satisfied user of EasyFind and other Devon Technologies apps, and have no financial or other involvement in the company.</sub>

Comment: Downvote? A cogent reason why my answer is not satisfactory is customary, but not required.